# Joomla category list issue

Tags: joomla

This is difficult to explain but I'll do my best.

I have a site with a number of articles grouped into different menus, which allows me to present relevant content to the visitor depending on what they are interested in. Each article may be in a number of menus.

I have also categorised each article based on the menu that it is most relevant to. I have done this in order to create a landing page using the category list component.

The issue I have is that the urls in the category list output do not relate to the active menu, when the article is in a number of menus. When you click on the article it takes you to the different menu. This issue is fixed if I unpublish the article from all other menus.  I understand this is because Single article menu id takes precedence over category menu id's.

I need a fix that selects the active menu id rather than the default.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla cannot do what you want to do by default. In short, you have multiple URLs for each article and you want Joomla to automatically know which context that article is displayed in in order to display the right URL. Joomla can't do this.

What you need to do is that you want to override the layout module for that category and create a code that will get the right URL based on the context you are in. Not a very easy thing to do but this is how it should be done.

Note that there are some extensions, such as flexicontent, that allow articles to be listed in multiple categories, and that will handle such URLs correctly depending on the context.